# Loading file contents irrespective of file extension

Tags: java, file-format

I want to display the contents of a file irrespective of file extension in editable format:

- doc
- pdf
- java file
- models (not so important)

Could you please let me know how to do in Java.

Is there any loader which I can buy to achieve this feature? I am ready for that also.

Comment: is this for java or javascript? In any case there is not a single file loader to handle all these file formats. So you would need to check the file extension and use an appropriate file loader/parser for this specific format. If you google around there are many (open-source) file parsers for many of these formats both for js and java. Some work better than others

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by 'in java', but there is always the quite simple.. [`Desktop.edit(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit-java.io.File-) which *"Launches the associated editor application and opens a file for editing."*

Answer (score 0):

there is no global loader, there is however atleast a loader for each of the file types you mentioned.

in `Java` you can use `FileDataSource  class` to determine the type of a file then simply have an `if statement` and use the appropriate `parser/loader` for each file type.